# Count on condition SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a table which contains some commercial Short text such as 'PVT, LTD' etc as in figure.

Secondly we have a new title received from another side every time such as 'Taha Zubair' and 'Taha PVT Ltd'.

Now i need to find just that if title contains a keyword, after scanning from database i need to return count only. If count is zero (0) means that title is simple as 'Taha Zubair' else return > 1 if title is some thing like that 'Taha PVT Ltd' or 'Taha Trust'

Image: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/195838

Furthermore i need to do it some thing like that it would be adjust in stored Procedure, using whole query in programming application(Inline query) would affect the performance.

if you have any question ask it without any hesitation........

Comment: Bad question - too specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as function

```
Create Function F_GetNonIndividual(@SearchStr nVarchar(100)) Returns int
as  -- use Select dbo.F_GetNonIndividual('Abc Solutions PVT LTD')
begin
    Declare @Result int
    Select @Result = Count(*) 
    from NonIndividualTitle
    where @SearchStr Like ('%'+NonIndivTitle+'%')
    Return @Result
end
```

as procedure

```
Create Procedure P_GetNonIndividual(@SearchStr nVarchar(100))
as  -- use EXEC P_GetNonIndividual 'Abc Solutions PVT LTD'
begin
    Select Count(*) 
    from NonIndividualTitle
    where @SearchStr Like ('%'+NonIndivTitle+'%')
end
```

as procedure with out param

```
Create Procedure P_GetNonIndividualOut(@SearchStr nVarchar(100),  @OutValue int out)
as  
begin
    Select @OutValue=Count(*) 
    from NonIndividualTitle
    where @SearchStr Like ('%'+NonIndivTitle+'%')
end
```

with query example

```
Declare @OutValue int
exec P_GetNonIndividualOut 'Abc Solutions PVT LTD',@OutValue out
print @OutValue
```

Comment: I'm fast with everything. Your answer still doesn't cover the question perfectly.

Comment: @bummi You understand my question very well and solve it, this a optimize way to do this, I don't know why other say its too specific.

Thanks a lot